# How to get a full height sidenav with Angular-Material

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I am using Angular-Material and have implemented a SideNav menu. When the screen size is small, the menu is hidden and when click on the Menu toggle button, the menu slides out from the left, with a full page height. When the screen is larger, the menu appears fixed to the left side, but not at full page height.

How can i make the fixed menu appear to be full page height.
I have been playing with the css and other md attributes, but just can't find out how.

```
<div ng-controller="appCtrl" layout="vertical" layout-fill>

<md-toolbar class="md.medium-tall app-toolbar">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools" ng-click="toggleMenu()">
        <button class="menu-icon" hide-sm aria-label="Toggle Menu">
            <md-icon icon="img/icons/ic_menu_24px.svg">
                <object class="md-icon" data="img/icons/ic_menu_24px.svg"></object>
            </md-icon>
        </button>
        <h2>
            <span>Dev.Material</span>
        </h2>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>

<section layout="horizontal" flex>
    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" component-id="menu" is-locked-open="$media('sm')">

        <md-toolbar md-theme="purple">
            <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Left</h1>
        </md-toolbar>

        <md-content class="md-padding" ng-controller="menuCtrl">
            <p>
                This sidenav is locked open on your device. To go back to the default behavior,
                narrow your display.
            </p>
        </md-content>
    </md-sidenav>

    <md-content flex class="md-padding">
        Some content !!
    </md-content>
```

and the controller:

```
(function () { 
'use strict';

var controllerId = 'appCtrl';
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
    ['$scope', '$timeout', '$mdSidenav', appCtrl]);

function appCtrl($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.toggleMenu = function() {
        $mdSidenav('menu').toggle();
    };
};    
})();

(function () { 
'use strict';

var controllerId = 'menuCtrl';
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
    ['$scope', '$timeout', '$mdSidenav', menuCtrl]);

function menuCtrl($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.close = function() {
        $mdSidenav('menu').close();
    };
};
})();
```

Comment: You may want to include what browsers you expect to support here... there are probably solutions using vh (viewport height) but this isn't available in older versions of CSS.  Alternatively you could use a directive that monitors any resize events and captures the updated height of the element using offsetHeight or perhaps screen.height and stores it somewhere (in a value or a service or factory whatever)

Answer (score 25):

I had the exact same issue with angular-material 0.6.0 rc1. (I used the code from the [demo site](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.sidenav)).

The problem does not come from the angular-material code, but from the parent css container of your page which is not full height.

Your page should have a structure like :

```
<ui-view class="ng-scope">
    <div ng-controller="appCtrl" layout="vertical" layout-fill>
        ... your md sidenav code here ...
    </div>
</ui-view>
```

The issue comes from the ng-scope class wich is not full height. In my case I just copy / past the code from the [demo site](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.sidenav) and add this im my cutom css file

```
.ng-scope { height: 100%; }
```

The result is a full height sidenav working fine in both locked-open and unlock mode.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `layout="column"` instead of `layout="vertical"`?

Comment: `layout="column"` doesn't work anymore. With the newer version of angular-material, `layout="vertical"` or `layout="horizontal"` should be used.

Comment: as of 0.8.3 (today): https://material.angularjs.org/#/layout/container (i.e. row / column)

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me...

1) Wrap your sidenav in a div that has a layout="vertical" like so...

```
<div ng-include="'scripts/shared/sidenav/sidenav.html'" layout="vertical"></div>
```

2) Add "flex" in your sidenav so that it will flex to fill out the full page height.

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" component-id="menu" is-locked-open="$mdMedia('sm')" flex>
```

Comment: This worked for me, while the other answers did not.

Comment: In an newer version, you may see: *"$media is deprecated for is-locked-open. Use $mdMedia instead"*. In that case use this `is-locked-open="$mdMedia('sm')"`

Comment: Thank you so much! The answer above this one helped with the parent container layout settings, but whenever I set `md-is-locked-open` to `true`, the sidenav only stretched the the minimum height required for its children. I didn't think to use `flex`.

Answer (score 13):

I fixed this same issue by adding a class to my sidenav with

```
position: fixed;
```

Comment: `md-sidenav { position:fixed }` and `md-backdrop.md-opaque { position:fixed }` was a quick easy fix for me. Thanks @phil_Igr

Comment: +million --> Took me a day to get this 'fixed'

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar Problem. Setting style"height: 100vh;" worked for me.You can also use a class.

```
<div layout="column" style="height:100vh;"></div>
```

layout="vertical" can also be used - it doesn't have any significant effect in my context.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `layout-fill` attribute on main `md-content` tag that has `ui-view` attribute set.

```
<md-content ui-view layout-fill layout-align="center center">

</md-content>
```

Comment: Make sure that parent containers are appropriately marked layout-fill as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `flex` in both the sidebar and content, as well as in the top container. This way you don't need to use any additional styles.

Here is your code working correctly (note that I updated some parts to the latest Angular Material version):

```
<div ng-controller="appCtrl" layout="column" flex>

<md-toolbar class="md.medium-tall app-toolbar">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools" ng-click="toggleMenu()">
        <button class="menu-icon" hide-sm aria-label="Toggle Menu">
            <md-icon icon="img/icons/ic_menu_24px.svg">
                <object class="md-icon" data="img/icons/ic_menu_24px.svg"></object>
            </md-icon>
        </button>
        <h2>
            <span>Dev.Material</span>
        </h2>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>

<section layout="row" flex>
    <md-sidenav flex class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')">

        <md-toolbar md-theme="purple">
            <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Left</h1>
        </md-toolbar>

        <md-content class="md-padding" ng-controller="menuCtrl">
            <p>
                This sidenav is locked open on your device. To go back to the default behavior,
                narrow your display.
            </p>
        </md-content>
    </md-sidenav>

    <md-content flex class="md-padding">
        Some content !!
    </md-content>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me (on `Angular Material 1.0.5`), none of the others below worked with the newest updates.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a sidenav outside a `<div>`. For example, just after the `<body>` tag, you could write:

```
<body layout="row">
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$media('gt-md')">
   <md-toolbar md-theme="deep-orange">
       <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools">Menu</h2>
   </md-toolbar>
   <md-content ng-controller="menuBar" md-theme="deep-orange">
       <md-button layout-align="left" ng-repeat="item in items" ui-sref="{{item.location}}" class="menu-item"
       md-ink-ripple="#bbb" aria-hidden="false"> 
<!-- the above <md-button> just repeats buttons created in the JS -->
        <span>{{item.label}}</span>
       </md-button>
   </md-content>
</md-sidenav>
<!-- Other content ... -->
</body>
```

This code will give you a fully vertical sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me for the angular material ver: **1.1.0-RC.5**, so I did it like this :

```
<body layout="column">

<div layout="row" ng-controller="reviewController" ng-cloak flex>

    <div layout="row">
            <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')" md-whiteframe="4" layout="column">
            <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo" class="md-medium-tall">
                <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Left</h1>
            </md-toolbar>
            <div ng-controller="LeftCtrl">
                <md-button ng-click="close()" class="md-primary" hide-gt-sm>
                    Close Sidenav Left
                </md-button>
                <p hide show-gt-sm flex>
                    This sidenav is locked open on your device. To go back to the default behavior, narrow your display.
                </p>
                <p flex>
                    hi
                </p>
                <p flex>
                    there!
                </p>
            </div>
        </md-sidenav>
        <div layout-column flex>

            <p flex>
                The left sidenav will 'lock open' on a medium (>=960px wide) device.
            </p>
            <p flex>
                The right sidenav will focus on a specific child element.
            </p>
            <div flex>
                <md-button ng-click="toggleLeft()" class="md-primary" hide-gt-sm>
                    Toggle left
                </md-button>
            </div>
            <div flex>
                <md-button ng-click="toggleRight()" ng-hide="isOpenRight()" class="md-primary">
                    Toggle right
                </md-button>
            </div>

            <md-content ui-view layout="column" flex></md-content>
        </div>
        <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-right md-whiteframe-4dp" md-component-id="right">
            <md-toolbar class="md-theme-light">
                <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Right</h1>
            </md-toolbar>
            <md-content ng-controller="RightCtrl" layout-padding>
                <form>
                    <md-input-container>
                        <label for="testInput">Test input</label>
                        <input type="text" id="testInput" ng-model="data" md-autofocus>
                    </md-input-container>
                </form>
                <md-button ng-click="close()" class="md-primary">
                    Close Sidenav Right
                </md-button>
            </md-content>
        </md-sidenav>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code is almost same as that given in the angular material docs and the *Js* file is also similar to that given in docs :)
**EDIT:**
More references:
1. https://gist.github.com/epelc/6aa345f4496776569830. Correct the depreciated value of `$media('gt-lg')` to `$mdMedia('gt-sm')`
2. https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1092

Answer (score 0):

The above issue was resolved only by modifying css and no need to change any code at all.

Solution-
.ng-scope { height: 100%; }

Answer (score 0):

```
<div layout="column" layout-fill>
<section layout="row" flex>
    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left"
                md-component-id="left"
                md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')"
                md-disable-backdrop
                md-whiteframe="4">

        <md-content>
            <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
                <md-button ng-click="closeSideNav()" class="md-primary">
                    Agregar Zona +
                </md-button>
            </div>

            <p hide show-gt-md>
                This sidenav is locked open on your device. To go back to the default behavior,
                narrow your display.
            </p>
        </md-content>
    </md-sidenav>
</section>
```

Test

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many things to fix this issue, and I finally was able to fix it by adding the uiview directly to my menu component:
`<menu uiview layout="column" class="menu"> </menu>`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try the other fixes with directives but I used this simple css and got what I needed. Any corrections or advice about this css would be welcome.

```
md-sidenav {
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```